# How to show that an m.d.s is not independent?

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity, martingale, conditional-variance

I have to prove that this Martingale Difference: $x_t = u_t u_{t-1}$ where $u_t \sim^{iid} (0, \sigma^2)$ is not serially independent, but am failing to do such thing.

I also have to prove that it's conditionally homoscedastic.

What I have tried so far is to show that $E[x_t^2|x_{t-1}^2] \neq E[x_t^2]$, and therefore it would not be serially independent because of the second moment, but in my view that would be proving that the process is conditionally *heteroscedastic*, instead of *homoscedastic*.

What am I doing wrong? How would you proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Does your notation mean only that the $u_t$ have zero means and variances of $\sigma^2,$ or is it perhaps intended to mean also that the $u_t$ have jointly Normal distributions?

Comment: @whuber it's not intended to mean a Normal distribution, this example came from Hamilton's Time Series Analysis where the exact distribution is not specified. In my view, to prove the lack of independency I could assume a Normal distribution as a counter-example, but I believe the conditional homoscedastic part should be shown more generally.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is possible for the $x_t$ to be independent when the $u_t$ are not Normally distributed: let each $u_t$ have a Rademacher distribution, for instance. That may be why you are finding it difficult to prove this result: it's not generally true!  BTW, in my copy of Hamilton there is an Example 7.8 that looks just like your question, but it explicitly states the $u_t$ are Normal.

Comment: @whuber Thanks! But even if I assume they are Normally distributed, I can't seem prove serial dependency: with my strategy mentioned above, I have reached the result $E[x_{t}^2] = \sigma^4 \neq E[x_{t}^2 | x_{t-1}^2] = u_{t-1}^2 . \sigma^2$, and, although this would prove dependency, I think it would also contradict the conditional homoscedastic part...

Comment: Hints: since now you are assuming Normality, you know higher moments are finite.  This enables you to compute, say, $\operatorname{Cov}(x_t^2, x_{t-1}^2).$ If this is nonzero then $x_t^2$ and $x_{t-1}^2$ cannot be independent, whence $x_t$ and $x_{t-1}$ cannot be independent.  As far as conditional homoscedasticity goes, you may be overthinking that, because the demonstration requires no calculation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although comments to the question indicate the original problem assumes the $u_t$ have *Normal* distributions, it is of interest to determine the extent to which this distributional assumption is needed to prove the $x_t$ are not serially dependent.

Let's begin, then, with a clear statement of the problem.  It focuses on three variables $(u_{t-1}, u_t, u_{t+1}).$  Suppose they are identically and independently distributed (*iid*); and that this distribution has zero mean and a finite variance of $\sigma^2.$  (We drop any Normality assumption.)  Out of these variables we construct two others, $x_{t+1}=u_{t+1}u_t$ and $x_t = u_tu_{t-1},$ which are products of successive $u$'s.  **Since $u_t$ is involved in the construction of *both* of the $x$'s, intuitively those $x$'s should not be independent.**  But how to prove this?

**This is trickier than it might appear,** because in simulations with Normally distributed $u$'s, the scatterplot of $(x_t, x_{t+1})$ shows a complete lack of correlation:

[image: Figure]

Indeed, if we try to demonstrate lack of independence by showing there is nonzero covariance, we will fail (because the $u$'s are independent and have zero mean):

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Cov}(x_t, x_{t+1}) &= E[x_tx_{t+1}]-E[x_t]E[x_{t+1}]\\
&= E[u_{t-1}u_t\, u_tu_{t+1}] - E[u_{t-1}u_t]E[u_tu_{t+1}]\\
&=E[u_{t-1}]E[u_t^2]E[u_{t+1}] - E[u_{t-1}]E[u_t]\,E[u_t]E[u_{t+1}]\\
&= 0-0 = 0.
\end{aligned}$$

**The simplest way I have found to demonstrate lack of independence** is to consider the *magnitudes* of the $x$'s.  The logic will be this: if we can show that some function $f$ (in this case, the absolute value) when applied to both $x$'s, produces variables with nonzero covariance, then the $x$'s could not originally have been independent.  (A simple proof is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872.)

So, **let's carry out the preceding calculations using the absolute values.**  We are permitted to do this because the finite variance of the $u$'s implies the expectations of their absolute values are finite, too (see [Prove that $E(X^n)^{1/n}$ is non-decreasing for non-negative random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244202)).  Let this common expectation be $E[|u_t|]=\tau.$  Then

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Cov}(|x_t|, |x_{t+1}|) &= E[|x_t||x_{t+1}|]-E[|x_t|]E[|x_{t+1}|]\\
&=E\left[|u_{t-1}|\right]E\left[|u_t|^2\right]E\left[|u_{t+1}|\right] - E\left[|u_{t-1}|\right]E\left[|u_t|\right]\,E\left[|u_t|\right]E\left[|u_{t+1}|\right]\\
&= \tau \sigma^2 \tau - \tau^4\\
&= \tau^2(\sigma^2 - \tau^2).
\end{aligned}$$

*Unless $\sigma^2=\tau^2$ or $\tau=0,$ this is nonzero and we are done.*

Because squaring is a convex function, [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) implies $\tau^2\le\sigma^2$ with equality if and only if $u_t$ is almost surely constant.

The case $\tau=0$ occurs when $|u_t|$ is almost surely constant, whence $u_t$ itself is either $0$ or takes on the values $\pm\sigma$ with equal probability (a scaled [Rademacher variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution)).  Both situations can be characterized as scaled Rademacher variables (with scaling factor $0$ in the first case).

That covers all the possibilities.  The result is,

> When  $(u_{t-1}, u_t, u_{t+1})$ are *iid* with zero mean, $x_t = u_{t-1}u_t$ and $x_{t+1} = u_t u_{t+1}$ are independent if and only if the $u$'s each have a scaled Rademacher distribution.

(The "if" part can be shown with a direct calculation: tabulate the eight possible values of $(u_{t-1}, u_t, u_{t+1}),$ compute the corresponding values of $(x_t, x_{t+1}),$ and verify independence.)

**To help the intuition,** here is a scatterplot of the absolute values in the preceding figure (shown on fourth-root scales to remove the skewness from the marginal distributions; if you like, the function involved is $f(x) =\sqrt[4]{|x|}$).  The red line is the least-squares fit to these fourth roots.  The correlation is obviously nonzero.

[image: Figure 2]