# Upper bound for absolute third central moment

Tags: probability, random-variable, moments, inequality

Suppose $X\in \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable with expected value $\mathbb{E}X = \mu$.  I ran across a proof which uses the inequality
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X - \mu|^3] \leq 2^3 \mathbb{E}|X|^3.
$$
Can anyone help me understand where this inequality is coming from?  Is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $p\ge 1.$  The $L^p$ norm of a random variable is defined as

$$|X|_p = \left(E[|X|^p]\right)^{1/p}.$$

[Minkowski's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) says this norm satisfies the triangle inequality.  Apply it to the random variables $X$ and $\mu=E[X]$ (a  number that can be considered a constant random variable) after observing

$$|\mu|_p=|\mu| \le E[|X|] = |X|_1$$

to obtain

$$|X-\mu|_p \le |X|_p + |\mu|_p \le |X|_p + |X|_1 \le |X|_p+|X|_p = 2|X|_p.\tag{*}$$

The last inequality applies the [power norm inequality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244202) $|X|_r \le |X|_p$ (whenever $r \le p$) to the case $r=1.$

When $p=3,$ cubing both sides of $(*)$ is equivalent to the inequality in the question.