# $\mathbb E[|X_n|^r]<\infty$ and $\mathbb E[|X_n|^r]\to \mathbb E[|X|^r]$ as $n\to \infty$

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, expected-value, convergence

> Let $\{X_n\}\xrightarrow{d}X$ and for some $p>0$, we have
> $$\sup_{n\ge 1} \mathbb E[|X_n|^p]<\infty$$
> Show that for any $r\in (0,p)$, we have
>
> a. $\mathbb E[|X|^r]<\infty$
>
> b. $\mathbb E[|X_n|^r]\to \mathbb E[|X|^r]$ as $n\to \infty$
>
> [Note: You must not use (b) to prove (a)]

I am pretty sure we need to use Skorohod Representation Theorem. Maybe, we also need to use the fact that
$$\{X_n\}\xrightarrow{d}X \iff \mathbb E[f(X_n)]\to \mathbb E[f(X)]\;\;\forall f\in \mathcal C_B(\mathbb R)$$
but I can't figure out how to do that.

The actual question had $\mathbb E[|X|^r]<\infty$ instead of $\mathbb E[|X_n|^r]<\infty$ which was wrongly written in the first question. So, now I have doubts in part (a) as well. The $1\le r\le p$ case can be tackled using some theorems done in class, but I can't find any argument for the $0<r\le 1$ case.

Comment: Are you interested only in part b?  It seems like it, but you should make that clear either way.

Comment: For (a), see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244202.

Comment: @jbowman yes, I'll place an edit

Comment: @whuber that was a nice answer! Do you have any insights on part (b)?

Comment: Cts mapping + skorohod + uniform integrability convergence theorem

Comment: Use Fatou's lemma and Skorohod theorem for part (a).

Comment: @Zhanxiong please elaborate how

Comment: @SayanDutta See my updated answer. There is no need to distinguish $r \in (0, 1]$ or $[1, p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Part (a)

I assume you already know how to prove $\sup_n E[|X_n|^r] < \infty$.

By continuous mapping theorem, $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ implies $|X_n|^r \overset{d}{\to} |X|^r$. It then follows by Skorohod's representation theorem that there exist $\{Y_n\}$ and $Y$ such that $Y_n \overset{d}{=} |X_n|^r$, $Y \overset{d}{=} |X|^r$, and $Y_n \to Y$ with probability $1$. Therefore, by Fatou's lemma,
\begin{align}
E[|X|^r] = E[Y] = E[\liminf_n Y_n] \leq \liminf_n E[Y_n] = 
\liminf_n E[|X_n|^r] \leq \sup_n E[|X_n|^r] < \infty. 
\end{align}

##### Part (b)

By continuous mapping theorem, $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ implies $|X_n|^r \overset{d}{\to} |X|^r$.  In view of Theorem 25.12$^\dagger$ (the proof to this theorem indeed uses Skorohod's theorem) in *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley, to show $E[|X_n|^r] \to E[|X|^r]$, it suffices to prove $\{|X_n|^r\}$ is [*uniformly integrable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Probability_definition).  Indeed, suppose by condition $\sup_n E[|X_n|^p] = M < \infty$, then for any $\alpha > 0$, we have
\begin{align}
& E[|X_n|^rI_{[|X_n|^r \geq \alpha]}] \\
=& E\left[|X_n|^p\frac{1}{|X_n|^{p - r}}I_{[|X_n| \geq \alpha^{1/r}]}\right] \\
\leq & \frac{1}{\alpha^{(p - r)/r}}E[|X_n|^p]
\leq \frac{1}{\alpha^{(p - r)/r}}M \to 0
\end{align}
as $\alpha \to \infty$.  This completes the proof.

---

$\dagger$

> **Theorem 25.12.**  If $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ and the $X_n$ are uniformly integrable, then $X$ is integrable and
> \begin{align}
> E[X_n] \to E[X].
> \end{align}

Comment: Excellent answer (+1)!