# Skew vs one sided standard deviation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, skewness

If a unimodal dataset x with mean 0

> E(x) = 0

is positively skewed

> E(x^3) > 0,

does it imply that mean squared value of positive data (y: x/ x>0) is more than negative data (z: x/ x<0) within x

> E(y^2) > E(z^2) ??

or that variance of y is more than variance of z??

Comment: No.  The reason why is that the third moment is not the same as the second moment: see the [power mean inequality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244202).  That provides a way to construct counterexamples.